# Update interval of Maven Central Repo

Tags: maven

Having zero experience with Maven, I am running a mvn clean install on a project and this is the error I get:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project dnasequencing.CompaNY.com: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.CompaNY.dnasequencing:dnasequencing.

CompaNY.com:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: dsr-kepler:dsr-kepler:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, dsr-parser:dsr-parser:jar:0.0.1-
SNAPSHOT: Failure to find dsr-kepler:dsr-kepler:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ was cached in the local repository, resolution 
will not be reattempted until the update interval of Maven_Central_Repo has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

Based on these error messages, what is an startingpoint I should take a look for finding what is going wrong?

Comment: First check the dependencies you have defined if they are correct (groupId, artifactId, version). Before that simply remove the folder in your local repository and retry it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force Maven to update snapshots with the `-U` flag.

As far as what is going wrong, you can always check out the actual Maven website with your browser and see if the dependency actually exists.

http://search.maven.org/

If the dependency is not hosted in Maven central, then it seems it is a local dependency that you have to install in your local cache (run `mvn clean install` from that project).