# I have added the required dependancies but still running into an error

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I am following this link [Link](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-annotations-1.html) to run my hibernate application. Although I have added all the required dependencies but it runs into following error.

```
The following artifacts could not be resolved: javax.security:jacc:jar:1.0, 
javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.0.1B: Failure to find javax.security:jacc:jar:1.0 in 
http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, 
resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central 
has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

The netbeans also shows the following message in its properties window.

Problems:
      * some dependency artifacts are not in the local repository.

My Pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.myProject</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernateTesting</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>hibernateTesting</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

       <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
      <version>3.0</version>
      <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
      <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.grlea.log.adapters</groupId>
      <artifactId>simple-log-sl4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.7</version>
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
      <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>jacc</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [When maven says "resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of MyRepo has elapsed", where is that interval specified?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856307/when-maven-says-resolution-will-not-be-reattempted-until-the-update-interval-of) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701532/force-maven-update or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12645707/update-interval-of-maven-central-repo or ...

Comment: Is this for a standalone or JEE app? If JEE, what version?

Comment: @Perception, It is a SE JDK 7

Comment: @BrianRoach, It is not a duplicate, my problem is related to two specific libraries ,please read the question again.

Comment: @BrianRoach, it is not because I have specified the libraries, and there is not accepted answer in those questions.

Comment: why you have <type>pom</type> for jta ?

Comment: @user395072, netbeans did it automatically, even when I remove it run into same error.

Comment: Remove it if you don't have dependent modules. Install the jacc jar manually if you don't have jacc in your local repository

Comment: @DanielMorgan - some of the dependencies you are trying to pull in only exist in deprecated repositories. I assume that you are trying to create a standalone SE app with Hibernate and JTA transactions? What JTA provider are you using?

Comment: @Perception, not sure, I am new to this, how to find out? I am just following the mentioned tutorial

Comment: @DanielMorgan - the tutorial you linked doesn't use Maven (it asks you to explicitly download JARs and include them in your build path). But with Maven your dependencies are automatically managed. You should only need the JUnit, Hibernate 3 and sl4j dependencies in your POM.

Comment: @Perception, referring to my Pom in the question I have them all dont I?

Comment: @DanielMorgan - you have some unnecessary ones (pretty much all the JTA stuff). You can't really use JTA without a provider implementation, and its totally unnecessary for the tutorial you linked.

Comment: @Perception, I have updated the pom but running into same problem

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24951/discussion-between-perception-and-daniel-morgan)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this repository to your pom.xml

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>JBoss Deprecated</id>
    <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/deprecated</url>
  </repository>
  <repository>
    <id>java.net</id>
    <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

JBoss repository will find javax.security.jcc and java.net repository will have javax.transaction.jta jar

`<repositories>` tags can go anywhere inside your `<project>` tags. I ususally declare them at the beginning of the pom.

Comment: I am trying to add it but it does not accept it where should I put this ? I mean in which part of my pom.xml ?

Comment: This goes into pom.xml as first child. 
Like - 
<project ...>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
...
...
<name>PorjectName</name>
<properties>
...
</properties>
<repositories>
...
</repositories>
<dependencies>
...
</dependencies>

Eclipse will show autocompletion based on given DTD.

Comment: Another similar option is
    <repository>
        <id>spring-maven-release</id>
        <name>Spring Maven Release Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/release</url>
    </repository>

Comment: The java.net repository is blacklisted according to Netbeans... any idea why or if its something I should be concerned about?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to clean and force an update of your maven repo like this:

```
mvn clean -U
```

Comment: my IDE is netbeans, where should I type it ?

Comment: On your console (cmd on windows) change into your project path, then run the command. If it says unknown command, you need to add the `C:/.../maven/bin` path to your [environment PATH variable](http://www.itechtalk.com/thread3595.html)

Comment: -U is for updating snapshots, not the release versions. The problem here is, in his settings.xml he may not have added these repositories, and maven is unable to find these packages. These are not available in standard repos, rather in http://download.java.net/maven/2/ and https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/deprecated